# Записать в одну переменную последовательность чисел

Tags: python

У меня проблема. Необходимо реализовать код. Условия реализации написаны в прикреплённом изображении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во втором изображении показан пример, как это должно выглядеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Последовательность чисел - это список или массив. В питоне соответствующая структура данных называется списком и записывается в квадратных скобках:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

Чтобы заполнить список `n` считанными целыми числами по одному на строке, можно сделать так:

```
a = []
for i in range(n):
  a.append(int(input()))
```

Если все числа записаны в строку через пробел, то количество знать не обязательно:

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Пример кода: https://ideone.com/OB5wob.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())

strings = [input() for _ in range(n)]

print(strings)
```